# Webview duplicate HTML problem

Tags: android

I load a url over the web containing images (their source is another
url).
when then view loads the html, it loads it without the images. after
few milliseconds, the images come along but then the html is redrawn,
and it does so over the previous html, causing it the web view to hold
2 htmls one over the other (very ugly result).

anyone knows why does that happen? how can I avoid that?

thanks,
Ori

Comment: Are you using a transparent background? I faced the same problem (on sdk 1.6) but only while I was using a transparent background

Comment: Actually, I do! I am using a transparent background. thanks!

Comment: Any solution to this that doesn't involve replacing the background?